# Counting results for cross join

Tags: join, count

How I can get count results with cross join?

Example cross join:

```
SELECT t1.firstname, t2.lastname
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table1 t2
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'count results' as well as the particular RDBMS so that we can get you the proper syntax?

Comment: I think count row after cross join. - I work with Oracle (11g). This is example to school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table1 t2;
```

or this format which will allow you to copy and paste any query without rewriting it and use it as a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT t1.firstname, t2.lastname
  FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table1 t2
) t3;
```

Comment: And how is that different from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table1 t2` ?

Comment: It's not... Most likely, the query optimizer will handle them the same.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you get a count with any other aggregate---all the columns that participate in the query need to be accounted for either in an aggregate or a `GROUP BY`.

```
;WITH table1(firstname, lastname, extra) AS
(
    SELECT 'bob', 'york', 'tuff'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'annie', 'murloc','guts'
)
SELECT
    t1.firstname
,   t2.lastname
,   COUNT(1) AS rc
FROM
    table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN table1 t2
GROUP BY
    t1.firstname
,   t2.lastname;
```